# Setting title attribute for each summary tag if its parent details tag is open?

Tags: javascript

I would want to add a 'show' or 'hide' title for each summary tag which depends if its parent details tag is open:

```
<details open>
        <summary>Summary 1</summary>
        <p>text 1</p>
</details>

<details open>
        <summary>Summary 2</summary>
        <p>text 2</p>
</details>
```

I tried this but it only shows 'hide' even though the details is not set to open:

```
var detailsElem = document.getElementsByTagName('details');
var summaryElem = document.getElementsByTagName('summary');

for (i = 0; i < summaryElem.length; i++) {
  if (detailsElem[i].display === '') {
  summaryElem[i].title = 'show';
  } else {
  summaryElem[i].title = 'hide';
  }
}
```

Comment: I would assume `detailsElem[i].display === ''` always evaluates to false, hence the `'hide'`. What is `display` supposed to be? This will likely just be `undefined`.

Comment: I am confused. I saw the default css settings of details is display:block. I tried detailsElem[i].display === 'block', but it would give a title of just 'show' whether its open or not. Kindly advise on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to access element css property. If so, then this line is wrong `detailsElem[i].display === ''`.

It should be `detailsElem[i].style.display`.

Also `display` cannot be empty and values can be either `display`, `inline`, `inline-display`, `none`...

Here's the better solution to access element css property. Use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method to get computed styles

```
var detailsElem = document.getElementsByTagName('details');
var summaryElem = document.getElementsByTagName('summary');

for (i = 0; i < summaryElem.length; i++) {
  var style = getComputedStyle(detailsElem[i]);
  if (style.display === 'none') {
    summaryElem[i].title = 'show';
  } else {
    summaryElem[i].title = 'hide';
  }
}
```